# How to output HTML Agility Pack for WP7

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, html-agility-pack

I have the below code to parse an section of an html page.

What I would like to know is how to output it to either a listbox or text box.

Whenever I try I get unhandled exceltion error

private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("http://www.sourceURL.com");

var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel");

 var value = node.InnerHtml;
 this.textBox1.Text = value;
```

Exception error is :

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message: NullReferenceException
```

Stack trace is:

```
   at Auckland_Airport.MainPage.PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

HTML Layout is

```
        <div id="FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel">

        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody>
            <tr class=""><td class="airline"><img src="/images/airline logos/US.gif" title="US AIRWAYS. " alt="US AIRWAYS. " /></td><td class="flight">US5316</td><td class="codeshare">NZ46</td><td class="origin">Rarotonga</td><td class="date">02 Sep</td><td class="time">10:30</td><td class="est">21:30</td><td class="status">CHECK IN CLOSING</td></tr><tr class="alt"><td class="airline"><img src="/images/airline logos/NZ.gif" title="AIR NEW ZEALAND LIMITED. " alt="AIR NEW ZEALAND LIMITED. " /></td><td class="flight">NZ6</td><td class="codeshare">&nbsp;</td><td class="origin">Los Angeles</td><td class="date">02 Sep</td><td class="time">19:15</td><td class="est">19:15</td><td class="status">DEPARTED</td></tr><tr class=""><td class="airline"><img src="/images/airline logos/AC.gif" title="Air Canada. " alt="Air Canada. " /></td><td class="flight">AC6093</td><td class="codeshare">NZ6</td><td class="origin">Los Angeles</td><td class="date">02 Sep</td><td class="time">19:15</td><td class="est">19:15</td><td class="status">DEPARTED</td></tr><tr class="alt"><td class="airline"><img src="/images/airline  class="d
    </div>
</div>
```

Clearer HTML

```
<div id="FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel">

   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody>
     <tr class="">
     <td class="airline"><img src="/images/airline logos/NZ.gif" title="AIR NEW ZEALAND LIMITED. " alt="AIR NEW ZEALAND LIMITED. " /></td>
     <td class="flight">NZ8</td>
     <td class="codeshare">&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="origin">San Francisco</td>
     <td class="date">01 Sep</td>
     <td class="time">17:15</td>
     <td class="est">18:00</td>
     <td class="status">DEPARTED</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="alt">
     <td class="airline"><img src="/images/airline logos/AC.gif" title="Air Canada. " alt="Air Canada. " /></td>
     <td class="flight">AC6103</td>
     <td class="codeshare">NZ8</td>
     <td class="origin">San Francisco</td>
     <td class="date">01 Sep</td>
     <td class="time">17:15</td>
     <td class="est">18:00</td>
```

Comment: Is there a div with `id="DivName"` in your markup? Can't see any from the snippet you posted.

Comment: @Darin Sorry, just edited. I am just trying to start simple and display all the html in the FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel div and then I will parse the individual td's. I just can't get it to output.

Comment: At what point do you get an exception. Maybe the stack trace you have added is not complete.

Comment: @Rhys, is the exception thrown because the div is not found, or it is thrown when you try to assign the value to the textbox?

Comment: @maxim It build fine, but when I try and run on the emulator it gets the exceptiomn and highlights `var value = node.InnerHtml;`

Comment: @Darin Im honestly not sure, It doens't give me much information. If I remove `var value = node.InnerHtml;` and  `this.textBox1.Text = value` then it build and runs on the emulator fine, it doesn't do anything, but it runs with exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HtmlDocument.Load function doesn't take a Uri as a paramter, it should recieve a structured HTML, that you have somehow retrieved from a server.

Here is the code for your case using the WebClient class to retrieve the HTML from server:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);

        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(@"http://www.aucklandairport.co.nz/en/FlightInformation/DomesticArrivalsAndDepartures.aspx"));

    }

    void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var html = e.Result;

        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

        var list = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").ToList();

        var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel");

        var value = string.Empty;

        if (node != null)
            value = node.InnerHtml;
    }
```

At the end, the `value` variable holds the inner HTML you need to further parse.

Comment: where would this code go? in place of the `var value = node.InnerHtml;
 this.textBox1.Text = value;`

Comment: thanks for that. I have added code but it errors on two things, one Empty should be capital and the other is that the var value is declared twice

Comment: Updated. Sorry. Well, it's a compile-time errors. When you do run the code, does the null reference exception still occures in this very same place?

Comment: thanks. That time no error. So that means that it can't find the nodes in the HTML?

Comment: It means, that in the resulting HTML page, that is served on a request to http://www.SourceHTML.com, there is no div element with an Id of FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel. Try inspecting the HTML returned from server by opening the URL in the browser, and looking at a page source code.

Comment: Found the problem and added full solution code to retrieve the required div contents.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is now disaplaying the div contents and I can parse down the individual elements/ Attributes. One issue though, there are mutiple listings and it only displays one. How would I disaply all?

Comment: I suggest you ask a different question for that, if you want the exact code, since this one has grown out of it's initial topic. But the main idea is not to call doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault but to call .Where(...ToList() to the all of the occurrences of divs.